# How to handle the Tap of a ViewCell defined in code in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tableview

I have a multiple ViewCell and ImageCell subclasses inside a TableView.

I would like to execute some code when the user taps the cell. The whole cell highlights whenever it's touched, but I don't see any event handler to use here.

Isn't there a XAML Tapped equivalent for this but in code only?

[image]

```
    private void SetTableView()
    {
        Content = new TableView
        {
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            Intent = TableIntent.Menu,
            Root = new TableRoot()
            {
                new TableSection()
                {
                    new ProfileCell(ImageSource.FromFile("profile_placeholder.png"), "Casa de Férias")
                },
                new TableSection()
                {
                    new InfoCell()
                    {
                        Type = InfoCellTypes.Pending,
                        Text = "Avaliação do Imóvel",
                        Detail = "Estado do Processo"
                    }
                }
            }

        };

    }
```

I'm sure there must be some API that handles this. Maybe I'm just not looking in the right place?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by adding a TapGestureRecognizer to the cell's view layout.

```
var absoluteLayout = new AbsoluteLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        photo,
        editImage,
        label
    }
};

var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};

absoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

View = absoluteLayout;
```

EDIT:

Or, a better alternative, using the Tapped property of the ViewCell, so it doesn't break the "Tap Animation":

```
Tapped += new EventHandler((e, s) => {

    if (command.CanExecute(null))
    {
        command.Execute(null);
    }

});
```